# socket appenders - basic example step by step

Tags: java, log4j, distributed, appender

Could you recommend simple tutorial about using log4j in distributed system, especially about SocketAppender?

I tried to find some basic examples, but I failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This one](http://nilshb.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/apache-log4j-as-log-server/) looks simple and straightforward. From the article:

> Example server startup  with [SimpleSocketServer](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SimpleSocketServer.html) (from the command line):

```
> java -jar log4j.jar org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer 4712 log4j-server.properties
```

> Now all you have to do is specify your appender on the client.
>
> Example appender:

```
> log4j.appender.SERVER=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
> log4j.appender.SERVER.Port=4712
> log4j.appender.SERVER.RemoteHost=loghost
> log4j.appender.SERVER.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

Comment: I still don't get it. I created [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759196/log4j-how-to-use-socketappender) with more details

Comment: @trebuchet I edited the answer to clarify the startup of the server. If this answers your new question, please consider removing it

Comment: Is it performance intensive?
Or it's better to use a shell script? Like http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer

Comment: I've never found it an issue, but as always, YMMV, and you should measure against your particular scenario

Comment: as Log4J 1.2 has reached end of life, is there a compatible solution with Log4J 2 SocketAppender ? It seems there is no SocketServer anymore..

Comment: @Donatello you can use FileBeats with ELK stack

Comment: @YasithaBandara yes, we are using EFK stack (FluentD) with JSON Template Layout from Log4j2. This is good for long history, but practically not so usable to do complex analysis... that's why I was looking for some alternative based on Socket appender