# log4j properties file - how to set threshold for socket appender?

Tags: java, log4j, appender

I have some problems with setting `Threshold` in properties file.

I created two files:

`log4j-server.properties`

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, CA, FA

#
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%t] [%m]%n
log4j.appender.CA.Threshold=DEBUG

#
log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FA.File=result.log
log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%t] [%m]%n
log4j.appender.FA.Threshold=DEBUG
```

and `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, server

log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.server.Port=4712
log4j.appender.server.RemoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.server.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

and I get logs:

```
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:27,490] [main] [Listening on port 4712]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:27,490] [main] [Waiting to accept a new client.]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:37,669] [main] [Connected to client at /127.0.0.1]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:37,669] [main] [Starting new socket node.]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:37,669] [main] [Waiting to accept a new client.]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,385] [main] [Connected to client at /127.0.0.1]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,385] [main] [Starting new socket node.]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,401] [main] [Waiting to accept a new client.]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,385] [request1343898881385] [public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,510] [request1343898881385] [public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,510] [request1343898881385] [public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,510] [request1343898881385] [public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,526] [SimpleSocketServer-4712] [Caught java.net.SocketException closing conneciton.]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,228] [main] [Connected to client at /127.0.0.1]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,228] [main] [Starting new socket node.]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,228] [main] [Waiting to accept a new client.]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,228] [request1343898882228] [public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,353] [request1343898882228] [public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,353] [request1343898882228] [public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,353] [request1343898882228] [public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,353] [SimpleSocketServer-4712] [Caught java.net.SocketException closing conneciton.]
```

while I need logs generated only by my program, not messages generated by the socket server itself

```
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,385] [request1343898881385] [public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,510] [request1343898881385] [public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,510] [request1343898881385] [public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:41,510] [request1343898881385] [public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,228] [request1343898882228] [public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,353] [request1343898882228] [public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,353] [request1343898882228] [public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)]
INFO [2012-08-02 11:14:42,353] [request1343898882228] [public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])]
```

I have tried almost every configuration, but I couldn't find a solution.

**EDIT:** 
I added `-Dlog4j.debug=true` line

and I got

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@35ce36.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@35ce36 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@35ce36.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@35ce36 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: [null].
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[DEBUG, CA, FA].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Parsing appender named "CA".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "CA".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%p [%d] [%t] [%m]%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "CA".
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [DEBUG].
log4j: Parsed "CA" options.
log4j: Parsing appender named "FA".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "FA".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [[%d] [%t] [%m]%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "FA".
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [DEBUG].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [result.log].
log4j: setFile called: result.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "FA" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
```

**EDIT:** After changing conversion pattern |I got

```
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:11,278] [main] org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer Listening on port 4712
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:11,278] [main] org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer Waiting to accept a new client.
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:22,125] [main] org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer Connected to client at /127.0.0.1
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:22,125] [main] org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer Starting new socket node.
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:22,125] [main] org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer Waiting to accept a new client.
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:25,664] [main] org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer Connected to client at /127.0.0.1
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:25,664] [main] org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer Starting new socket node.
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:25,664] [main] org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer Waiting to accept a new client.
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:25,664] [request1343902405664] aspects.ReportingAspect public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:25,789] [request1343902405664] aspects.ReportingAspect public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:25,789] [request1343902405664] aspects.ReportingAspect public java.lang.String hello.Hello.greeting(java.lang.String)
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:25,789] [request1343902405664] aspects.ReportingAspect public static void hello.RMIClient.main(java.lang.String[])
INFO  [2012-08-02 12:13:25,789] [SimpleSocketServer-4712] org.apache.log4j.net.SocketNode Caught java.net.SocketException closing conneciton.
```

Comment: Please edit the log pattern to include the log level and post the new output +  add a short explanation what you expect to see.

Comment: Have you tried with `log4j.appender.server.Threshold=ERROR`?

Comment: @AaronDigulla done. log level is always info

Comment: @m.abbas I've tried. then I got logs **only** from server socket

Comment: Ah ok, but i can't see how it could be happen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand how log4j applies thresholds:

First the threshold of the logger is applied. If the logger doesn't have one, then the threshold of the parent logger is applied. If the message can't pass any of these, no appender will ever see it.

In the next step, all appenders will see the message and they will again filter it using their threshold.

So if the threshold of any logger is higher than that of the appender, the appender will never see the message.

How can you solve that? You can use a logger that is "closer" to the message source. If you want to log from a class below `com.something.x.y.z`, you can define a logger for `com` and give it a threshold + an appender.

It will see messages before the root logger, so you can use that to redirect parts of the messages.

Also keep in mind that using package/class names is just a convenience. Logger names can be anything. So you could define a logger called `RMI` or `network` and use that. Since it's not part of the usual logger hierarchy, only specific messages will go there.

Just don't forget to set `additive` to `false` as necessary to make sure messages are processed only once.

**[EDIT]** My guess is that the wrong config is read. Add `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to the command line to see which config files log4j reads and how it configures itself.

**[EDIT2]** Use the log pattern `%-5p [%d] [%t] %c %m%n` to see which logger creates which message. You can then raise the threshold of the ones that you don't want.

Comment: Still don't get it. I have only one logger in aspectJ-class, so it logs from all my classes. And  logs from server socket are generated automatically, I didn't create any logger for this. Any advice?

Comment: Add `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to the command line to see which config files log4j reads and how it configures itself.

Comment: I added `-Dlog4j.debug=true` result. I configured files as I was told [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759196/log4j-how-to-use-socketappender)

Comment: The new output shows that neither of the properties files in the question are loaded: `log4j.properties` doesn't contain a line `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA, FA` and `log4j-server.properties` uses `ERROR` threshold.

Comment: But my guess is that you simply see output of loggers that you don't expect. Make log4j print the names of the loggers and then make sure you only see those that you want.

Comment: Please give example configuration code. Tips are very hard to translate into actual configuration.

Comment: @apennebaker: Please ask a new question explaining exactly what you need to achieve.