# How to make 2 or more java project write in a single log file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using `log4j` to write all the logs in a file.
i have 2 different java projects say `proj1` and `proj2`, where `project1` is required project for `proj2`. I have added `proj1` as a dependency for `proj2`.

proj1 has `log4j` setup done and is working fine.
Now my problem is when I am running a method in `proj2`, it will call `proj1` as well.
So I want to have a single logfile for both the projects.

Any input please?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to write to a single log file but which way is best depends on a couple of details which you omit.

If `proj2` includes `proj1` as a library, you can make it use `proj1`'s log4j configuration file. This works because you only have a single VM. The most simple solution here is to either copy the first project's config into the other or not give the second project any log config; it will then read the config from its dependencies.

If `proj2` starts `proj1` as an external process, you need to configure both projects to use a SocketAppender since only a single Java VM can ever write to a single log file.

Related:

- [log4j: How to use SocketAppender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759196/log4j-how-to-use-socketappender)

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I have made it working. Here is what i have done.I just copied proj1's log4j.properties file to proj2 and then i had single log for any execution between proj1 and proj2.

Comment: you may use root logger configuration for external appender.there will be no need of raplacing or copying log4j.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem but i got the solution and
 have configured my log4j.xml like this:

**used a appender:**

```
<appender name="FILE1" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler" />
        <param name="File" value="E:/OESController.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="20KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5l - %m%n%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


<!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="error" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />     
    </root>
```

**Note**:**Root logger logs for entire application.**

let me know if you still face the problem.