# How to create log file that placed in network path using log4j?

Tags: java, logging

Hello **is there a way to create log file in network path** such as in LAN folder, but by folder that have date pattern like this:

```
\\10.0.0.1\logs\2014\NOVEMBER\logs.log ?
```

I *already have log file XML based, using java util logging*, but it has problem while log viewer parse the log file.

thanks for your response.

Comment: You can use `SocketAppender of Log4j2` See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SocketAppender**. It allows **to write log on remote host**. [Log4j2 - SocketAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender).

**Sample Log4j Configuration :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <Socket name="socket" host="localhost" port="9500">
            <SerializedLayout />
        </Socket>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="socket"/>
    </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Also have a look at below posts :

1. [How to use SocketAppender ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759196/log4j-how-to-use-socketappender)
2. [Log4j SocketAppender and socket server example](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/08/log4j-socketappender-and-socket-server-example/)