# What's the correct way to aggregate Jboss logs in a clustered environment?

Tags: java, jboss, cluster-computing, log4j

We are using Jboss 7.4.0 with two nodes that each have their own rolling file appenders. What we would like to do is redirect these two outputs in a unique file, "outside" both Jboss nodes. I tried to use SocketAppenders, with a manually started Log4J server, but it doesn't work...

```
<custom-handler name="SOCKET" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender" module="org.apache.log4j">
  <level name="DEBUG"/>
  <formatter>
     <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %X{user} %X{app} [%C:%M:%L] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
  </formatter>
  <properties>
     <property name="Port" value="4712"/>
     <property name="RemoteHost" value="127.0.0.1"/>
  </properties>
```

The only things in the log4j server is this :

```
[2015-04-01 10:31:24,969] [main] [Listening on port 4712]
[2015-04-01 10:31:24,981] [main] [Waiting to accept a new client.]
```

I've read that the SocketAppender doens't exists anymore in Jboss 7+, but to be honest, the Jboss documentation is incomplete, missing, or incorrect at best.

So, what's the correct (or best) way to do this, without reinventing the wheel?
Should we use asynchronous rolling file appenders?
Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Have you added reference to socket in your root-logger?

Comment: Yes <root-logger>
                    <level name="INFO"/>
                    <handlers>
                        <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                        <handler name="FILE"/>
      <handler name="SOCKET"/>
                    </handlers>
                </root-logger>

Comment: Have you started the client for accepting the server request

Comment: I've followed this guide (from the recommanded answer) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759196/log4j-how-to-use-socketappender
I've started the Log4J server, and then started my two Jboss nodes. I can see the logs in console, in their respective files... but not in the Log4J server.

Comment: can you list out the steps you followed for running this configurations.. seem you are not running it correctly

Comment: On my Jboss, I've added in both nodes, in domain.xml, the appender described in my first post. Then, I've added the SOCKET appender to my root logger.

Separatly, I've created a log4j.properties file, next to the log4j.jar, and i've run the log4j server using the first comand from the linked post

Then, I've started the Jboss domain controller, and both nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these Steps to use it correctly this might solve your problem..

1> First Create log4j-server.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%t] [%m]%n
```

2> Now Run the following command at reciever side

```
java -classpath log4j.jar org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer 4712 log4j-server.properties
```

now it will listen to the port `4712` and store the logs in the `logfile.log` which you have defined in your `log4j-server.properties` file

3>In log4j.xml file add the following appender to send the logs to the server with the specified port.

```
<custom-handler name="SOCKET"  class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender" module="org.apache.log4j">
<level name="DEBUG"/>
<properties>
  <property name="Port" value="4712"/>
  <property name="RemoteHost" value="127.0.0.1"/>
</properties>
```

Do not specify any formatter in this configurations.
and do not forget to add `SOCKET` in `root-logger` of `log4j.xml`

Comment: I've followed these steps, but.. I don't have a log4j.xml. I've tried to put this same configuration in my domain.xml (jboss_node1/domain/configuration/)

Comment: Ok, I've added the appender from the jboss web console, and now, I can see part of my logs in logfile.log. So it should only be a matter of configuration now, thanks :)