# How to view log4j logs running inside a docker container?

Tags: java, linux, log4j, docker

As a newbie to Docker: I am using a Docker host to run around 11 containers, and one of the containers is running java application, in which I used log4j logging to log. How can I access only the logs while running the Docker [compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). I have tried to capture the logs to a log4j.log file, but this only creates after the termination of the java application.

Comment: It may more useful to setup  a network logging.  You send the logs outside the container (say to a central location) and analyse it.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759196/log4j-how-to-use-socketappender

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have configured *log4j* to log into std out and you are running application by using commnad: `java -jar ...` you should be able to check logs using:

```
$ docker-compose logs name_of_container
```

Comment: It works!, thanks for the tip, One small issue is that, with one server I have used supervisor to spawn two processes, one for execution of java with ant script and other for starting tomcat7. In this case am not able to see the logs.

Comment: Generally it is not a good idea to have supervisor or run more than one application inside single container. It can cause you a problem for example if one of the applications will stop working.

Comment: Yes I did observe that. Will try not to. Thanks!