# How to get rid of :"Log4j: ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.socketAppender"

Tags: java, log4j, wildfly, java-ee-8

I am currently refactoring very old code in an JavaEE Wildfly software. Upon executing I always get the following two warnings:
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.socketAppender
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "socketAppender".

In my POM I am dependent to:
org.apache.log4j(core) 2.17.1
org.sl4j(api&simple) 1.7.30

The existing Log4j-property file looks as follows:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.socketAppender

log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be org.apache.log4j.SocketAppender

Comment: Does this answer your question? [log4j: How to use SocketAppender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759196/log4j-how-to-use-socketappender)